# Derivative of an ideal in a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ denote the polynomial ring $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ or the formal power series ring $\mathbb C[[x_1,\dots, x_n]]$.
Suppose $I\subset R$ is an ideal. Consider the following ideal
$$
d(I) = \text{the ideal generated by} \ \{  \partial_{x_j} f \ : \ f\in I, 1\le j\le n\}
$$
Is there a terminology or a name for $d(I)$?

Personally, I am interested in the relations between $I$ and $d(I)$.
An obvious one is that if $I=0$, then $d(I)=0$. What else? For example, when do we have $I \supset d(I)$ or $I\subset d(I)$?

Comment: One can see that $d(I)\subseteq I$ iff $I=R$ or $I=0$ (where $R$ is the polynomial ring in consideration), indeed, let $f$ be a nonzero polynomial of minimal degree $n$ in $I$. If $f$ is constant, we have $I=R$, otherwise, $f$ is non-constant so there is $j$ such that $\deg \partial_{x_j} f<n$ and $\partial_{x_j} f\neq 0$, so it is not in $I$ by the minimality of $n$. I'm not sure about the rest of the question.

Comment: Giving it some more thought, one has that $I\subseteq d(I)$ since for all $f\in I$ we have $\partial_{x_1} (x_1 f) = f + x_1 \partial_{x_1} f$, so $f=\partial_{x_1} (x_1 f) -x_1 \partial_{x_1} f$, which is an element of $d(I)$ since $f, x_1 f\in I$, so in fact $d(I)=0$ iff $I=0$. I still don't know if there's standard terminology or more that can be said about it.